Cannot change page-margins with KOMA-2 letter
Here is the "minimal working example". As is -- with the default margins -- it renders Ok:

The first line ends with the "Third." sentence.
The fancy header on the second page looks fine, with the sender's name at right.

#LyX 2.3 created this file. For more info see http://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 544
\begin_document
\begin_header
\save_transient_properties true
\origin unavailable
\textclass scrlttr2
\begin_preamble
\listfiles
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Here you can modify the layout of your letter
%% Have a look at the KOMA script documentation
%% for details. Most commands are commented out
%% here (i.e. we use default settings)
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%% Load an *.lco style file (see KOMA documentation)
\LoadLetterOption{DIN}%                          

%% THE CLASS OPTIONS
%% Remove preceeding '%' to uncomment an item
\KOMAoptions{%
%,headsepline=true%            separate the header with a line on page >1
%,footsepline=true%             separate the footer with a line on page >1
%pagenumber=botcenter%   position of the page number (see docu)
,parskip=false%          Use indent instead of skip (more options cf. docu)
,fromalign=center%        alignment of the address
,fromrule=false%    separate the address with a line?
,fromphone=false%         print sender phone number
,fromfax=false%          print sender fax number
,fromemail=false%           print sender e-mail address
,fromurl=false%               print sender URL
%,fromlogo=true%         print a logo (position depends on fromalign)
%,addrfield=false%        print an address field?
,backaddress=false%  print the back address?
%,subject=afteropening,titled% alternative subject layout and position
%,locfield=narrow%      width of the (extra) location field
,foldmarks=false%      print foldmarks?
,twoside=false
%,numericaldate=true%  date layout
%,refline=wide%             layout of the refline
}

%% Customize Separators
%\setkomavar{placeseparator}{ -- }
\setkomavar{backaddressseparator}{ $\cdot$ }
%\setkomavar{emailseparator}{ --> }
%\setkomavar{enclseparator}{ > }
%\setkomavar{faxseparator}{ --> }
%\setkomavar{phoneseparator}{ --> }
%\setkomavar{subjectseparator}{ >>> }

%% Customize fonts
%% Use LaTeX's standard font commands
%% Modify with \setkomafont or \addtokomafont
%% (see KOMA documentation)
%% \setkomafont{backaddress}{\rmfamily}
%\setkomafont{descriptionlabel}{}
%% \setkomafont{fromaddress}{\large}
%% \setkomafont{fromname}{\scshape}
%\setkomafont{pagefoot}{}
%\setkomafont{pagehead}{}
%\setkomafont{pagenumber}{}
%\setkomafont{subject}{}
%\setkomafont{title}{}
\end_preamble
\use_default_options true
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\language american
\language_package default
\inputencoding koi8-u
\fontencoding global
\font_roman "lmodern" "default"
\font_sans "default" "default"
\font_typewriter "default" "default"
\font_math "auto" "auto"
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts false
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100 100
\font_tt_scale 100 100
\use_microtype false
\use_dash_ligatures true
\graphics default
\default_output_format default
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command default
\index_command default
\float_placement h
\paperfontsize default
\spacing single
\use_hyperref true
\pdf_bookmarks true
\pdf_bookmarksnumbered false
\pdf_bookmarksopen false
\pdf_bookmarksopenlevel 1
\pdf_breaklinks false
\pdf_pdfborder true
\pdf_colorlinks false
\pdf_backref page
\pdf_pdfusetitle true
\papersize letterpaper
\use_geometry true
\use_package amsmath 1
\use_package amssymb 1
\use_package cancel 1
\use_package esint 1
\use_package mathdots 0
\use_package mathtools 1
\use_package mhchem 1
\use_package stackrel 1
\use_package stmaryrd 1
\use_package undertilde 1
\cite_engine basic
\cite_engine_type default
\biblio_style plain
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date false
\justification true
\use_refstyle 0
\use_minted 0
\index п÷я─п╣пЄп╪п╣я┌пҐя▀п╧ я┐п╨п╟пЇп╟я┌п╣п╩я▄
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\secnumdepth -1
\tocdepth 0
\paragraph_separation indent
\paragraph_indentation default
\is_math_indent 0
\math_numbering_side default
\quotes_style english
\dynamic_quotes 0
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 1
\paperpagestyle fancy
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Name

\lang english
Boo Hoo
\end_layout

\begin_layout SenderAddress

\lang english
0 Privacy Drive
\begin_inset Newline newline
\end_inset

Hootown, MA 02020
\end_layout

\begin_layout Address

\lang english
Mayorate,
\begin_inset Newline newline
\end_inset

Hootown, MA 02020
\end_layout

\begin_layout Subject

\lang english
Bananas
\end_layout

\begin_layout Opening
Dear sir or madam!
\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
This is the first sentence.
 It is very short, so I'll need to add more.
 Third.
 Fourth.
 Fifth.
 Sixth.
 Seventh.
 Eighth.
 Nineth.
 Tenth.
\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset Newpage newpage
\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Closing
Thank you very much for your consideration.
 Sincerely yours,
\end_layout

\begin_layout Signature

\lang english
Boo Hoo
\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document

If, in an attempt to widen the text, I specify the inner margin as 1cm (which inserts the \leftmargin 1cm line into the file), I observe the following:

Nothing obviously changes for the first page. The first line still ends with the "Third." sentence.
The fancy header on the second page shifts too far to the right (not left!), with the author's name way too close the paper-edge.

Could someone explain both of these findings?
Further, if I set the outer margin too -- \rightmargin 2cm -- the fancy header moves even further to the right (with the sender's last name off the page completely), without any effect on the margins of the actual text.
What am I doing wrong?
Update: removing the twoside=false part from the \KOMAoptions makes the layout react normally to margin-settings again. Could someone, please, explain, why that matters?

Off-topic note: You are using \pagesize letterpaper but load DIN.lco in the preamble. Please note, that this results in a warning, because DIN.lco is made for a4paper not for letterpaper.

BTW: twoside=false is the default of scrlttr2. Loading DIN.lco is also the initial default. Loading it explicitly makes only sense, if you load another lco before and want to reactivate the settings of DIN.lco. fancyhdr is not really recommended with KOMA-Script classes. And it is not a KOMA-Script package. I currently do not understand, if using fancyhdr is part of your problem. Note also, that LyX sometimes adds strange code even using \AtBeginDocument and therefore executed after the preamble code.

I've explained the problem with option twoside already in my answer to your previous question. You can find there also other notes, e.g., about using letterpaper with DIN.lco. So IMHO this question is a duplicate.
